# Increment field value by 1 from the last value if a boolean field is checked - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I have a simple model of application:

```
class Application_data(Models.model):
    application_sn=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    applicant_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    sanction_sn=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_sanctioned=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

In this model, I may have multiple applications, not sanctioned. I want that if I set `is_sanctioned` as true,`sanction_sn` gets incremented by 1, and for the next random row from the db, if I set the boolean as true, `sanction_sn` gets again incremented by 1, i.e. 2. And setting boolean as False should also decrease the values of sanction_sn, accordingly.

For example:
in a set of 130 rows, at 124th sanction_sn, I set the boolean as False, so 123 records before that particular record, have no effect at all but after 123, 125th record will have sanction_sn as 124 and 130th record will have sanction_sn as 129.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a presave django signal to achieve this.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Application_data)
def sanction_sn_changer(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        obj = sender.objects.get(application_sn=instance.application_sn)
    except sender.DoesNotExist:
        obj = None

    if obj:
        if obj.is_sanctioned != instance.is_sanctioned:
            if instance.is_sanctioned:
                instance.sanction_sn = obj.sanction_sn + 1
            else:
                instance.sanction_sn = obj.sanction_sn - 1

pre_save.connect(sanction_sn_changer, sender=Application_data)
```

I think this way, it will check the current value of the Application_data instance and make the necessary changes